Unable to create DbContext due to GetDatabaseLock method missing in Npgsql EF Core 9.x
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project using Entity Framework Core and Npgsql for PostgreSQL. I'm trying to create a DbContext to manage my database, but I'm encountering the following error when I try to add a migration or run the application:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'RuntimeType'. The exception 'Method 'GetDatabaseLock' in type 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Migrations.Internal.NpgsqlHistoryRepository' from assembly 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' does not have an implementation.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

I've confirmed that all my Entity Framework Core and Npgsql packages are on version 9.x, but the issue persists. The following includes a list of what I have tried to fix the issue

Verified all package versions are aligned at 9.x
Cleared NuGet cache and reinstalled the packages
Attempted to downgrade to a stable version (7.x) which resolved the issue, but I need to use 9.x features
Cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times


Log a bug with the NpgSql provider team. EF Core 9 is still in Alpha state so stuff will be more fast and loose for providers to keep up with, EF Core 8 should work, worst case make a temporarily bootstrapper to do the DB migration with EF Core 8 while your application uses the experimental EF Core 9, then move migration across to the EF Core 9 compiled DbContext.

Could you please share the code to replicate the issue of the dbcontext class. could you share the version which is you are using with your project as well.  and as Steve said you could log the request with the version you are using on Github

You have to match the exact preview.# version with your latest Npgsql, which would be 9.0.0-preview.3.24172.4 at the time of writing. Microsofts EF Packages are ahead of Npgsql

FYI I'm working on bringing the PostgreSQL provider up to date with the latest EF previews - you'll have to wait until that happens.

Hello. Can you please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79062461/ef-core-tools-and-runtime-and-postgresql-driver-version-conflict

Upgrading to 9.0.2 for Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL solved for me.
